# PHP - MySql : How to store and retrieve checkbox value with other option

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, checkbox

I using checkbox to get and store interest of user.

[image]

Store these data in database mysql with comma separated

[image]

My php code for retrive these data and display in html page

```
<?php

....

// Get data
$result = profile($uname);
$result['interest'] = explode(',', $result['interest']);

print_r($result['interest']); // output: Array ( [0] => option1 [1] => option2 [2] => option3 )

?>

....

<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-check checkbox-style">
        <label class="label-weight">Interests</label><br>
        <label class="form-check-label label-weight">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="interest[]" onclick="return interest_validate(this);" id="selectall"><span class="check-label-pad"> Select all</span></label></label><label for="" class="opacity-set label-set" id="select-label"></label><br>
        <label class="form-check-label label-weight">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="interest[]" onclick="return option_select(this);" value="option1" <?php echo in_array('option1',$result['interest']) ? 'checked' : ''; ?>><span class="check-label-pad">Option 1</span></label><br>
        <label class="form-check-label label-weight">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="interest[]" onclick="return option_select(this);" value="option2" <?php echo in_array('option2', $result['interest']) ? 'checked' : ''; ?>><span class="check-label-pad">Option 2</span></label><br>
        <label class="form-check-label label-weight">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="interest[]" onclick="return option_select(this);" value="option3" <?php echo in_array('option3', $result['interest']) ? 'checked' : ''; ?>><span class="check-label-pad">Option 3</span></label><br>
        <label class="form-check-label label-weight">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="interest[]" id="other_checkbox" onclick=" return other_validate(this);" value="other"><span class="check-label-pad"  >Other</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;</label><input type="text " class="text-style-other opacity-set" id="other-text" onblur="return other_text_validate();" />
        <label for="" class="opacity-set label-set" id="other-text-label"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

> **Issue**  : in edit mode, I am using "[in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)" for to give as default checked to checkbox as per database value. But how to check
>   "Other" (check attached image) option and display it's value ? which
>   condition i need to add here? how to store in one field "interest"
>    in database

Comment: what's result print_r($result)?

Comment: In your table there is `other` in 2nd row. So is it value of check box OR text box that user filled?

Comment: @paranoid, updated question. please check

Comment: @B.Desai, yes, it is one of the option to solve this

Comment: Have you stored  value of textbox in db?

Comment: No, only one field "interest" for it. how to manage in one field?

Comment: You can insert textbox value with all values separted with any caharecter like `:` Example: your field should be: `option2,option3,other:xyz`. where xyz is yoyr textbox data

Comment: Yes, best option, but how to manage in html ?

Comment: in_array() is not working here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert data with `:` delimiter. then to display data try following code:

Example: stored data is "option2,option3,other:xyz";

```
<?php
$result['interest']="option2,option3,other:xyz";
$result['interest']=explode(":", $result['interest']);
$txt_value="";
if(count($result['interest']) >= 2)
  $txt_value = $result['interest'][1];  

$result['interest']=explode(",",$result['interest'][0]); 


?>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-check checkbox-style">
        <label class="label-weight">Interests</label><br>
        <label class="form-check-label label-weight">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="interest[]"  id="selectall"><span class="check-label-pad"> Select all</span></label></label><label for="" class="opacity-set label-set" id="select-label"></label><br>
        <label class="form-check-label label-weight">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="interest[]" value="option1" <?php echo in_array('option1',$result['interest']) ? 'checked' : ''; ?>><span class="check-label-pad">Option 1</span></label><br>
        <label class="form-check-label label-weight">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="interest[]"  value="option2" <?php echo in_array('option2', $result['interest']) ? 'checked' : ''; ?>><span class="check-label-pad">Option 2</span></label><br>
        <label class="form-check-label label-weight">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="interest[]" value="option3" <?php echo in_array('option3', $result['interest']) ? 'checked' : ''; ?>><span class="check-label-pad">Option 3</span></label><br>
        <label class="form-check-label label-weight">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="interest[]" id="other_checkbox" <?php echo in_array('other', $result['interest']) ? 'checked' : ''; ?>><span class="check-label-pad"  >Other</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;</label><input type="text " class="text-style-other opacity-set" value="<?=$txt_value?>" id="other-text"/>
        <label for="" class="opacity-set label-set" id="other-text-label"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Prefect solution for me with one rule : **must store "Other" option at end of the string of interest field.**

Comment: Thank you for solution..!  :)